# Detect Call On Hold

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I wanted to know if there is any definitive way to know if the call is put on hold by the receiver on the receiver side only.

Now I checked the [Telephony](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) documentation, and this shows that there are three states for a call :

1. `CALL_STATE_IDLE`: When no call activity is there
2. `CALL_STATE_RINGING`: When a new call is ringing and waiting to be taken up.
3. `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`: At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.

Here lies the problem, `OFFHOOK` takes the active and hold state as one. There seems to be no way to distinguish between them.
But an interesting observation I made was that dialler recieves a notification when the call is retrieved from hold, that means there exists some way to know the difference. Hence, I would be obliged if you assist me in finding that way.

Comment: You can find more detail against various call status even `HOLD` under broadcast action `ACTION_PRECISE_CALL_STATE_CHANGED` in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java

Comment: this link might help you   http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-read-precise-state-of-outgoing.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the current Telephony APIs doen't let you read the precise call state.

In this commit, however
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/c5ac15a3e11c03951e269b243674858411204b67
You can see a proposal for a precise call state monitoring.

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/60660/
Here you can see that at Feb 13 5:26 AM this "Change has been successfully merged into the git repository."

This means that sooner or later we'll see it in a future Android release.

Comment: In the last release, the precise call state has been restricted to system application only. This API is hidden and not available for third app.

Comment: http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-read-precise-state-of-outgoing.html

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi very interesting "polling" solution. Looks like it's still not possible to "listen" to the precise state changes...

Comment: when i used this code few months ago, I was able to get three states, but unable to detect if an outgoing is answered.

Comment: Is it still a system app permission only?